# How to collect and compute multiple DiagnosticArrays out of the /diagnostics topic?

Tags: diagnostics, ros2

I'm currently implementing a "error collector" node in C++ for ROS2. This should subscribe on the /diagnostics topic, go through the topic and collect the errors of the different node, interpret them and combine the matching Errorcode which will be transmitted over CAN bus.

As each node should be independant from the others, each published his diagnosticArray in the /diagnostics topic, so that the topic will contain multiple diagnosticArrays.

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1680098196
    nanosec: 141203557
  frame_id: Safe Container
status:
- level: "\x02"
  name: System
  message: Invalid Config
  hardware_id: ''
  values: []
---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1680098512
    nanosec: 141935388
  frame_id: Sensor Front
status:
- level: "\x02"
  name: System
  message: Can Unknown Message
  hardware_id: ''
  values: []
- level: "\x02"
  name: Front Sensor
  message: Screen polluted
  hardware_id: ''
  values: []
```

Now my question is : How can I access the different diagnosticArrays?

I had a look in the ROS2 Aggregator example, but there only one diagnosticArray is used....

Many Thanks in advance for your ideas...

As the diagnosticArray aren't indexed in the diagnostic_msgs::msg I didn't find how to access the different Arrays..

Answer (score 0):

//Hi,You can try like this:

```
auto array = diagnostic_msgs::msg::DiagnosticArray(); auto status =
diagnostic_msgs::msg::DiagnosticStatus(); status.level=49;
array.push_back(status);
```

//to access:

```
//your callback 'msg'
auto lvl=msg->status[0].level;
```